# Showing "New content" form on main theme

Tags: theming, nodes, forms, users

I'm using drupal 8
I have a page with diferent content types like "beers, wines, etc". I want to let users publish their own content inside this content types, but I want a form in the main theme, no administration theme. How can I do it?

Comment: I believe this is as easy as not allowing that role the permission to use the administration theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 8 there is the [entityform_block](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform_block) module which gives you the option to display an entity form as a block. 
You just need to go to Blocks, select Place block in the region you want and select Entity form.
When you add your from you can select Entity Type + Bundle, where you have to select your content type and also in which pages you what this block being visible.

Keep in mind that using this way, on submit the user will be redirected to the content page but you can write your custom handler using hook_form_alter.

Comment: Hey Ismini, thanks for your answer. I think this is what I need, but I don't find this block type in the list... I am searching for "Entity" and nothing appears... Maybe I need some module to find it?

Comment: Oops yes. you are right! I changed the answer!